# how to add custom boolean classes to tailwind similar to the class dark in darkMode?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to reuse a component in react with tailwind but some presentation aspect of it is different in two places. I want to use similar things to dark:{class}. so I want to have something like variant_a:{class} in some places while variant_b:{class} on others. and when I call the component I want to specify which variant I'll be using for that component such as class="variant_a".

I could create two components but I think this will be a more elegant solution. any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register some [static variants via a Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#static-variants), like:

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

module.exports = {
  // …
  plugins: [
    plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
      addVariant('variant_a', '.variant_a &');
      addVariant('variant_b', '.variant_b &');
    })
  ]
}
```

These could then be used like:

```html
<div class="variant_a">
  <div class="variant_a:text-blue-500 variant_b:text-red-500">
    I will be blue.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="variant_b">
  <div class="variant_a:text-blue-500 variant_b:text-red-500">
    I will be red.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following PostCSS installation, you can add a `@layer` in your `global.css` file where you have imported the tailwind base classes. `@layer components` lets you extend the component layer to define your component classes to be used in the project.

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/*Your tailwind configurations*/
@layer components {
  .btn-blue {
    /* Here you can use @apply directive to use tailwind classes */
    @apply bg-blue-500;
  }
}
```